# OpenTok to create a Sesssion

Tags: android, opentok

I am referring to the point from the below website:

https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/android/basic-video-chat/step-2/

> **Before you can test the application, you need to set up a web service to handle some OpenTok-related API calls. The web service
>   securely creates an OpenTok session.**

How to do this step in Android Studio? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

From that website you mentioned, follow the Opentok PHP link through to the Github page:
https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-php

Scroll down and there's a link to deploy to Heroku that should shortcut a lot of work. Alternatively, there's also instructions there if you'd like to do it yourself and host locally.